# Turning off Find My iPhone

Tags: iphone, apple-id, password

I just got a new iPhone 6. I synced it to my computer through the last backup I had saved from my old phone. Unfortunately, at the time I was using a different Apple ID, and this ID no longer exists. I want to sync it to my new Apple ID, but first I have to turn off Find My iPhone using the old ID. I can't do this because it no longer exists, but it still asks for the password.

I've tried entering in old passwords and sending an email to reset the password, but none of it works.

Comment: Http://Iforgot.apple.com is the place to start, otherwise the posted answer is correct

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to take your iPhone along with the sales receipt to an Apple store.

Answer (score 1):

Apple IDs are never deleted. So try to reset the AppleID password first. Then remove the old iPhone from that account. After that use the new Apple ID with iPhone 6.